# Who are some renowned academicians or PhD guides in Information Security?

Tags: professional-education, research, academia

The question might seem opinion based, but I wish to know who are some people who are academicians or PhD guides in the field of Information Security?

Comment: The answers to this question are very likely to be opinionated and soon are going to be outdated.

Comment: Information security is a very broad field. Which field do you want to do a research in?

Comment: I'm open to all. But application security piques my interest

Comment: This is not only opinion-based, but completely undefined, and impossibly broad. It is also not in the format that works for StackExchange, in general.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few

- Dr. Ron Ross NIST Fellow
- Dr. Whitfield Diffie, Cybersecurity Advisor
- Dr. Dan Geer, In-Q-Tel
- Dr. John McLean, Naval Research Laboratory
- Prof. Angela Sasse, University College London
- Prof. Fred Schneider, Cornell University
- Mr. Phil Venables, Goldman Sachs
- Prof. David Wagner, University California at Berkeley
- Dr. Jeannette Wing, Microsoft Research
- Dr. Matthew Green
- Bruce Schneier
- Eduard Karel de Jong